# Pin Button to Bottom Right Corner of TextField IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, storyboard, uitextfield

I would like to pin a button to the bottom right corner of a textfield. I completed this in Android using a relativelayout. I don't know how to do this in IOS. I attempted to set top and bottom constraints, but it didn't work. 
Help?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbnuY.png)

Comment: In your storyboard, set bottom and right constraints for button equal to bottom right of text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have successfully pinned the button. 
This is what I did. 
I used control+click to set bottom and trailing constraints between the textfield and the button. Then I set equal height and equal width constraints between the button and the view and used a multiplier.

Comment: Doesn't that mean your button will overlap entirely over your textField, or do you make the multiplier <1 which means it scales down? That's kinda glitchy, you could instead wrap the textfield and button in a container view, and make the button overlap the textfield in this container view .. although your text could get behind the button

Comment: I forget what exact value I used. But I think I used .1? I have a different problem I am trying to solve now. Do you know how I would temporarily play a gif over the screen? But the background of the gif would still be transparent.

Comment: Try this library: https://github.com/kaishin/Gifu. The GIF layer should be over your content layer. Make sure the gif has transparency.

Answer (score 0):

```
    UITextField * rightField;
    rightField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    UIImageView *rightImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    rightField.rightView = rightImageView; // Set right view as image view
```

set UITextField rightView as your button. Here in my example I added UIImageView to UITextField rightView.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this when I get home. I at school right now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a storyboard you'd probably want something like this if I'm not mistaken:

[image: result]

To do this set the following **trailing and leading** constraints on your textfield:

[image: textfield]

Your button should have the following constraints:

[image: button]

Comment: Thanks for the response! However I would like the button in the text field. Also the text field is much larger. How would I get the button into the text field in the bottom right corner?

Comment: Can you give me an example on what you want to achieve? It's not possible to put a button IN a text field, but maybe thats not even the solution to your problem. @androidcoder1234

Comment: I am trying to achieve the above image (see edit in post). I achieved this on Android using a relative layout.

Comment: I can help you with that, but are you sure its a textfield and not a textview?

Comment: I have solved the problem. See my answer above. It is a textfield.